# Rails: Capistrano change database.yml to database.yml.example causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

When I deploy a new app to nginx using Capistrano. 
I follow tutorial to do `git mv database.yml database.yml.example` and `git mv secrets.yml secrets.yml.example` , then created a new `database.yml` file on remote server. But now when I want to run app on my local mechine, it shows me an error

> No such file - ["config/database.yml"]

Because there is no database.yml on my local repo.
Can I create an new and empty `database.yml` to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The guide just tells you that storing database credentials in a repository is bad practice and you shouldn't do it, but it doesn't mean you don't need to have this files at all.You application still needs it, so you definitely need to create it, just don't store it in main repo with code, this security critical information is better to store it elsewhere you decide to keep your authentification data like separate repository for credentials, key-pass storage or whatever place you want for such critical information.

**PS** Of course, if you just learning since it's not a big deal, you COULD keep your "root-123" credits in repository, but it's better to develop right habit from the beginning or at least get the idea why it should be separated.